# Replace / to _ in mysql replace

Tags: mysql

I have a small code that allows me to add custom name to a new field from an existing field but it does not remove / (slash) to _ (underscore).

```
UPDATE `custom` SET custom_url = LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, ' ', '_'), '(', ''), ')', ''));
```

How can I re-write this code so that it also allows me to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward slashes have no special meaning in MySQL, just add an extra replace.

```
UPDATE `custom` 
SET custom_url = LOWER(
                   REPLACE(
                     REPLACE(
                       REPLACE(
                         REPLACE(Name, ' ', '_')
                       , '(', '')
                     , ')', '')
                   ,'/','_')
                 );
```

If you want to remove the `/` then replace `,'/','_')` with `,'/','')` in the bottom replace part.