# Replacing forward slashes in mySQL REPLACE query

Tags: php, mysql, replace

All I'm looking to do is to replace a any occurence of a foward slash (`/`) in one of my table fields. The following code doesn't seem to be working:

```
UPDATE table SET numberClean = REPLACE(REPLACE(numberNotClean, '.', ''), '\/', '');
```

It's currently running in my php script, all the rest of my replace queries (which also escape characters) are working correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forward slashes don't need to be escaped

```
UPDATE myTable SET fieldName=REPLACE(fieldName,'/','')
```

Your current code will replace any occurrence of `\/` in the string. Since a forward slash doesn't need to be escaped, MySQL considers your `\/` as just a string without any special meaning.

**[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)**

Comment: For the reverse situation: `UPDATE tblBookList SET BookImageLocation=REPLACE(BookImageLocation,'\\','/')` Note the double forward slashes "\"

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET numberClean = REPLACE(numberClean, '/', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it with

```html
UPDATE table SET numberClean = REPLACE(REPLACE(numberNotClean, '.', ''), '/', '');
```

Please look at the below URL
[Replace / to _ in mysql replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326859/replace-to-in-mysql-replace)

Answer (score 0):

Forward slashes in `MySQL` have no special meaning, which means that you shouldn't escape them:

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `numberClean` = REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
    `numberNotClean`, 
    '.', 
    ''
  ), 
  '/', 
  ''
);
```